# Fixed CSS Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've recently resolved an issue that has been bothering me for a while with my CSS Navigation Bar. Now I have the problem of fixing it to the top so that it scrolls down when you scroll the page. I know the thing I need to add is Position: fixed; but I don't know where to add it.

My recent attempts resulted in the text being fixed but the background of the Navbar wouldn't. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My CSS

```
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;


}
#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #232323;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;



}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s;
  -moz-transition: color .15s;
  -o-transition: color .15s;
  transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -90px;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
  transition: all .3s .1s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 65px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fafafa transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #323232;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 206px;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 190px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #cc2c24;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: With your css only, it is really hard to help you out. Please post some html. It would be even better if you create a jsfiddle!

Comment: Try it out a little bit using a browser code inspector (firebug etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add it to the overall container of all your nav items, from your `css` file I would guess this is the `DOM` element with `id="cssmenu"`.  Also you will want to add `top: 0px;` as well to assure that it stays at the 0 position.

**EDIT**:

css:

```
#my-nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="my-nav-bar">
        <!-- nav bar content -->
    </div>
    <!-- page content -->
</body>
```

Now the `div` with `id="my-nav-bar"` will stay fixed to the top of the window.

See this [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SpJCX/1/) I just made

Comment: I'm not too sure on how I go about that, I'm not really advanced with Css yet O.o

Comment: Both answers seem to work great but now my Navbar has gone to 50% width O.o

Comment: @user2957819 try adding `width: 100%`, should make sure it fills the whole top.  See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpJCX/1/) I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you #cssmenu is your main nav container, maybe give a try on

```
    #cssmenu {
      position: absolute;   
   }
```

Comment: position:fixed; would be a more appropriate answer since he wants to keep it fixed while scrolling.